# What does the first star (*) mean in visudo command restriction

Tags: linux, redhat, visudo

Restriction example in visudo :

```
(ALL) NOPASSWD: (ALL) /bin/cp * /var/www/html/*
```

I understand most of it, its just the first star driving me nuts. My best guess is , its either for command options or source path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for both options and the source argument. Any command line that starts with `/bin/cp` and includes `/var/www/html` would match.

However this rule might not be what's intended. It is rather **dangerous**. You can misuse this rule to bypass the destination restriction.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, that's why I could not understand it. Any idea how do I separate options and source? Will double star do it (/bin/cp * * ...)?

Comment: @Adrian One way to restrict copying to a specific destination directory would be to make a script that does just that and validates the input on the way. Doing this with just the sudoers wildcard patterns is fragile and prone to abuse.